# How to get localised name of the month with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am working with a multiple language angular project using ngx-translate and I am trying to display the name of the current month in the main dashboard. At this moment, I am getting it in english only and displaying it with the format pipe, like this:

```
<p class="style-title-calendar">{{ dateSelect | date : "MMMM, yyyy" }}</p>
```

The `dateSelect` is as it follows:

```
this.dateSelect = new Date();
```

And in my json files for each language, the name of the month is already translated, but I don't know how to print the name of the month with the `translate` pipe.

Comment: In this case I would split the date into year and month parts and show in the desired format and I wouldn't use the `date` pipe at all. And after that you can simply use the `| translate` pipe on the month part.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same idea but it got rejected by boss, so I have to do the more complex way for some reason

Comment: Ok, but something like that should be possible: `{{ dateSelect | date : "MMMM" | translate }} {{ dateSelect | date : "yyyy" }}`. I didn't test it.